# how to send a link of plant UML configuration

Tags: plantuml

I have an activity diagram created in plantUML:

```
@startuml
|#LightBlue|ILC Running Continously|
start

note
ILC grabs data from
VOLTTRON message bus
for HVAC system
and electric meter
end note

repeat :Calculate averaged power;
repeat
repeat while (Is Averaged Power above "Demand Limit"?) is (no)
->yes;

repeat: Calculated needed demand reduction;
:Calculate AHP Wieghts;
:Curtail selected loads;

note
Typical to VOLTTRON edge
device on interacting 
with building systems via
protocol driver framework
end note

:Wait in Minutes "Control Time";

backward: Curtail more;

note
Devices already curtailed
saved in ILC agent memory
end note

repeat while (Is "Demand Limit" goal met?) is (no)
->yes;
backward: Manage Demand;

@enduml
```

Is it possible to send someone a link of the entire configuration which is NOT just the output picture link which is in the snip below but the entire configuration for someone else to modify?!

[image]

Comment: I think it will work when you use the same link but just replace the part `/png/` by `/uml/` like in http://www.plantuml.com/plantuml/png/SyfFKj2rKt3CoKnELR1Io4ZDoSa70000 and http://www.plantuml.com/plantuml/uml/SyfFKj2rKt3CoKnELR1Io4ZDoSa70000

Comment: AWESOME....I couldn't find documentation anywhere on how to do this. If you post an answer ill hit the green check box

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know whether or not it is documented anywhere but from experience / trial error and observing the URLs with the plantuml webserver one can see that the URLs are:

- uml: http://www.plantuml.com/plantuml/uml/SyfFKj2rKt3CoKnELR1Io4ZDoSa70000
- png: http://www.plantuml.com/plantuml/png/SyfFKj2rKt3CoKnELR1Io4ZDoSa70000
- svg: http://www.plantuml.com/plantuml/svg/SyfFKj2rKt3CoKnELR1Io4ZDoSa70000
- ASCII art: http://www.plantuml.com/plantuml/txt/SyfFKj2rKt3CoKnELR1Io4ZDoSa70000

in other words the part uml / png / svg /txt changes according to the outcome.
Also when one tries a none existing part it is reverted back to uml